# attribute value

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

I have an atribute test that I get the value of like this

```
$('#row').attr("test");
```

now I need to put this in a loop and get the value but its not working.
This is what I am doing

```
for(var i=0; i=mySpansCount; i++)  
{  
 var x=($('#row').attr("test"));  
 alert(x[i]);    
}
```

All I am getting in alert box is undefined.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using `id="row"` more than once?

Comment: I can see about 3 or 4 possible errors here. `i` and `I` are not the same variable, neither of them are referred to in the loop, `mySpansCount` is never changed so the loop should either die after one loop or go on forever, and jQuery attribute values are always strings, so `x[k]` doesn't really make much sense, unless you're looking for the kth character of the string, and I think that syntax doesn't work in all browsers, anyway. As such, I'm not really sure what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: row is only used once. alert(x[k]);      was suppose to be alert(x[i]); but still having probs

Comment: @user295189 - Fix the question if it's wrong, you can't correct answer an incorrect question, that's like having a math problem with the wrong numbers and complaining the result is wrong each time.  For row, how could it be used once?...what are you looping through if it's only used once?

Comment: @user295189 - The other question remains...what are you looping through? Right now you're looping through and alerting the *same* value `n` number of times...this doesn't seem very useful.  Since IDs are unique, this isn't making much sense, can you clarify it a bit?  You're described what you've tried, that's good...but we also need what you *want* to happen, describe what the desired outcome is, possibly the markup you're running against as well.

Comment: @user your script is still faulty on multiple levels. The element queried will always be `#row` (the ID *must* not exist more than once in the document!) also, `x[i]` will never work because `x` is not an array, but a string. Try `alert(x);` (Update: @Nick was faster....)

Comment: @Pekka - your's was spelled correctly though, evidently I stop proof-reading my comments after 6pm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that maybe you need to use `.each()` like this:

```
<div id="row">
    <span test="start">Hi </span>there, <span test="middle">I</span> am testing this <span test="end">out</span>.
    <div><span test="nested">Bye!</span></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $('span', '#row').each(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('test'));
    });
});
</script>
```